# How can I traverse through the childs of random id firebase? (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I want to travel through the child values of the random ids generated. Apparently I want to check if the foodname matches with the requested name of not. I have seen the solution for Java but couldn't figure out on for NodeJs.

This is what I have tried but it only returns the exp_date of the top most random id.

```
app.intent('getDate',(conv,{foodname})=>{
  return admin.database().ref("/users/${conv.user.id}").once('child_added',function(snapshot){
        conv.ask("${snapshot.val().exp_date}");

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right now attaching a listener to `/users/${conv.user.id}`, that listens for `.once('child_added'`. So your callback gets called with a snapshot of the first child under `/users/${conv.user.id}`. If you want to get all children under `/users/${conv.user.id}`, you can do something likel:

```
app.intent('getDate',(conv,{foodname})=>{
    return admin.database().ref(`/users/${conv.user.id}`).once('value',function(snapshot){
        var msg = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            msg = msg + child.val().exp_date;
        });
        conv.ask(msg);
    });
});
```

So this:

1. Uses literal backticks around `/users/${conv.user.id}`, since you're using template strings.
2. Listens for the `value` event, which means you get triggered with a single snapshot for all child nodes under `/users/${conv.user.id}`
3. Loops over all these matching child nodes with `snapshot.forEach()`.

Comment: I had used the literal backticks for `/user/${conv.user.id}` but removed it while posting the question due to some issue with the formatting. Anyway, the answer helped me. Thanks.